# Почему get(Calendar.MONTH -1) возвращает год?

Tags: java, calendar

```
Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
int nowMonth = cl.get(Calendar.MONTH); // 0
int nowMonth2 = cl.get(Calendar.MONTH - 1); // 2017?
```

В январе `nowMonth` - `0`, хорошо.
Почему `nowMonth2` - `2017`? Т.е. возвращает год.

Comment: int nowMonth2 = cl.get(Calendar.MONTH ) - 1;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что константа `Calendar.MONTH` равна `2`, а `Calendar.YEAR` - `1`.
Метод `.get()` возвращает значение соответствующего поля. Поэтому если вы ему передаёте `1` (а `Calendar.MONTH - 1` - это `2 - 1 = 1)`, то получаете год.